# JSF PrimeFaces simple example: blank page only

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried [this](http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html) example using Primefaces-3.3.1, JSF 2.1, Glassfish 3.1.2 and IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.3 as IDE. Added PF's jar to WEB-INF/lib directory and created 'test.jsf', where I putted the example.
As a result I see blank page. Chrome understands it like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><head></head><body><h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <p:editor>

</p:editor></h:body>
  </body></html>
```

What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ `4. JSF 2.0 Serlvet Configuration`

Comment: Thanks! Changing web.xml helped.

Comment: You've also got <head> and <h:head> tags which isn't right, get rid of the <head> tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you should modify your web.xml

like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

take a look at this [JSF 2.0 Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/) `4. JSF 2.0 Serlvet Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you build a JSP or XHTML page, and you enter in the navigator it doesn't work like a JSF page.

To fix it you need to view the web.xml and change the url-pattern like said Daniel before.

For example, if you have a page called:

> index.jsp

and you have this in your web.xml

> < url-pattern>*.jsf< /url-pattern>

You need to access through the URL

> http:// localhost:8080/project/index.jsf